# QAbstractModel with a QCheckbox with icons for on/off state

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QTableView` that I populate with a `QAbstractTableModel`. One column, say the 3rd, should contain a `QCheckBox` for which I would like to display two icons instead of the standard appearance for a `QCheckBox`, one icon for the `on` state and another for the `off` state.

To do so, I derived a model from `QAbstractTableModel` and also a delegate from `QStyledItemDelegate`. The problem is that the `setData` of my model is never called and the only icon that appears is then the `off` one. Here is some code snippets of my test implementation

**MyModel.h**:

```
#ifndef MYMODEL_H
#define MYMODEL_H

#include <vector>
#include <QAbstractTableModel>

class MyModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyModel(QObject *parent = 0);

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const override;

    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const override;

    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const override;

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override;

    bool indexIsValid(const QModelIndex& index) const;

    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const override;

    bool setData(const QModelIndex& index, const QVariant& value, int role) override;

private:
    std::vector<bool> _states;

};

#endif // MYMODEL_H
```

**MyModel.cpp**:

```
#include "MyModel.h"

MyModel::MyModel(QObject *parent) : QAbstractTableModel(parent)
{
    _states.resize(5,false);
}

int MyModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return 4;
}

int MyModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return 3;
}

QVariant MyModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
{
    if (role != Qt::DisplayRole)
        return QVariant();

    if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal)
        return QString("Col");

    return QVariant();
}

QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{

    if (!indexIsValid(index))
        return QVariant();

    if (role==Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        if (index.column() != 2)
            return QString("blabla");
    }
    else if (role==Qt::CheckStateRole)
    {
        if (index.column() == 2)
        {
            Qt::CheckState state = _states[index.row()] ? Qt::Checked : Qt::Unchecked;
            return state;
        }
    }
    return QVariant();
}

bool MyModel::setData(const QModelIndex& index, const QVariant& value, int role)
{
    if (!indexIsValid(index))
        return false;

    if (role==Qt::CheckStateRole)
    {
        {
            if (index.column()==2)
                _states[index.row()] = value.toBool();
        }
    }

    emit dataChanged(index,index);

    return true;
}

bool MyModel::indexIsValid(const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    return index.isValid() && index.row() < 5;
}

Qt::ItemFlags MyModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (!indexIsValid(index))
        return Qt::ItemIsEnabled;

    if (index.column() == 2)
        return QAbstractTableModel::flags(index) | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt::ItemIsEditable;

    return QAbstractTableModel::flags(index);

}
```

**MyDelegate.h**:

```
#ifndef MYDELEGATE_H
#define MYDELEGATE_H

#include <QStyledItemDelegate>
#include <QModelIndex>
#include <QObject>
#include <QSize>
#include <QSpinBox>
#include <QIcon>

class MyDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyDelegate(QObject *parent = 0);

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const override;

private:

    QIcon _icon;
};
#endif // MYDELEGATE_H
```

**MyDelegate.cpp**

```
#include "MyDelegate.h"
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QPainter>

#include <QApplication>
#include <QStyleOptionViewItem>

MyDelegate::MyDelegate(QObject *parent) :
    QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{
    _icon.addPixmap(QPixmap(":/selected.png"), QIcon::Normal, QIcon::On);
    _icon.addPixmap(QPixmap(":/deselected.png"), QIcon::Normal, QIcon::Off);
}

void MyDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{

    if (index.column() != 2)
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter,option,index);
    else
    {
        bool value = index.model()->data(index).toBool();
        QStyleOptionButton buttonVis;
        buttonVis.rect = option.rect;
        buttonVis.iconSize = QSize(10,10);
        buttonVis.icon = _icon;
        buttonVis.state |= QStyle::State_Enabled;
        buttonVis.state |= value? QStyle::State_On : QStyle::State_Off;
        buttonVis.features = QStyleOptionButton::None;
        QApplication::style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_PushButton,&buttonVis, painter);
    }
}
```

would you have any idea about what I missed to make it work ?

Comment: Just from a glance: You write that you wanted to populate "two columns" with icons, then in the delegate you have a check `index.column() != 2` ? Also your delegate probably needs a mouse click handler, because all it does for now is to _draw_ the icon.

Comment: Maybe you wanted to access the data of the CheckStateRole in the delegate? `index.model()->data(index, Qt::CheckStateRole).toBool();`

Comment: ... errr, instead of `toBool()` you need to convert it like that: `...data(index, Qt::CheckStateRole).value<Qt::CheckState>() == Qt::Checked`

Comment: @leemes I tried to access the Qt::CheckStateRole specifically  and to use `static_cast<Qt::CheckState>(index.model()->data(index,Qt::CheckStateRole).toUInt())` but unfortunately it does not help

Comment: @antipattern sorry for the mistake, it was the 3rd column in the example showed. The message has been edited accordingly

Comment: @antipattern you were right. I did not handle the mouse event properly in the editorEvent method. Thanks.